# Script to display only comments from /etc/services file

Tags: awk

I need to write a bash script that takes service name as a parameter and display only comment that is after hash symbol in /etc/services but I have no idea how to cut only the comment part.

The ,,it's working solution'' for me is to just:

```
grep "^$1" /etc/services | awk '{print $3,$4 ...
```

but I don't think this is a good one

I'm searching for something like:

[find the service] -> print only the part from # till the end of the line

I'm still learning so any solution with explanation or just a hint will be very helpful for me.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can best help you.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are this is what you're looking for:

```
awk -v svc="$1" '($1==svc) && sub(/[^#]+#/,"")' /etc/services
```

but without sample input/output it's a guess.

The above will work using any awk in any shell on every Unix box.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```sh
SERVICE_NAME=linuxconf; grep -Po "^$SERVICE_NAME.*# \K.*$" /etc/services
```

-P tells grep to use perl regex.

-o trims the output so that it only includes the regex match.

\K tells the regex engine to exclude previously matched part of the string from the match, i.e. only the part after \K will be present in the final match.

Comment: This is correct, indeed one doesn't need `awk` for this. But [one doesn't need `cat` either](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUOC) as `grep` knows how to search a file. One last thing: can you please add some explanation on your regex and the `-oP` option, as requested by the OP?

Comment: Agree about cat. As for the regex, -P tells grep to use perl regex, -o trims the output so that it only includes the regex match.
\K tells the regex engine to exclude previously matched part of the string from the match, i.e. only the part after \K will be present in the final match.

Comment: @basper, could you please provide some line from the /etc/services file to test

Comment: Ok, im sorry maybe I re-typed it wrong for the first time... 
It's working.Thanks!

Comment: Now this answer looks perfect! :-) @basper: if you are happy with it, please accept it and don't hesitate to vote it up.

Comment: You should mention that will only work on systems that have GNU grep (and where the service name doesn't contain any regexp metachars like `.` but idk if that's possible in a service name). You should also anchor it to the start of the line or you'll get false partial matches, e.g. `bar` will match `foobar`.